# Refactoring a C# derived class with method dependancies

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, refactoring

I want to get your opinion on this.

I have a class which is derived from a base class.  I don't have control over the code in the base class and it is critical to the system that I derive from it.

In my class I inherite two methods that are critical to the system and are used in pretty much every function, many times.

I intend to refactor this derived class and extract some classes from it  - this won't be a problem.  What I'm not sure about is, is it worth extracting class if I have to constantly make call backs to my main class to access the two methods (or public wrappers to the methods)???

Thanks

Comment: Well its not really a problem with refactoring my code - its more that when I do - every class will need to make calls back to the main class.  I am currently doing that with my event handlers - but it makes sense in that context.  However, literally any class I create that does anything useful will need to make calls back to the main class

Comment: I don't see any problem - are you worried about dependencies to the main class? That will not change with extracted classes unless Proxy or Mediator pattern is used.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm worried about.  It just feels instinctively wrong to be creating classes which all have a dependancy on one class!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure in your case but refactoring is for your benefit and others. You have to weigh the cost of refactoring with benefit of code up-keep. The point of method extraction (and not copy-and-place) is that it centralizes it and makes it easier to deploy changes. So it is probably worth it if you have the code everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your concern about dependencies, it sounds like you'll probably have to let the "main class" continue to be the "front door" for now--i.e., the class that everyone calls.  Let the main class delegate to the extracted classes, not the other way around.  Without more details, that's all I can think of to say.